# SELECT Statement with "IF" included in WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, select, where-clause

[image: Sample Data]

I have a query that's pulling in data for all Product Serial Numbers above that are in Workflow "A". However, in some cases there are serial numbers in both Workflow A and B.

When this happens, I don't want to pull that serial number at all. However, I cannot just do a simple statement like

```
WHERE Workflow <> 'B'
```

because it still pulls in the row of data where the `Workflow = 'A'`.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem in a `SELECT` statement or does it need to be dealt with further upstream?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data. That screenshot would have been easier to type; text is far more accessible and allows people to reproduce your issue and a better chance at an accurate answer on first try. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/20091109)

Comment: Probably it is not just B but anything other than A, right?

Comment: Also, the requirement is unclear. If there is a workflow C, is it okay to include the row with A, or not?

Comment: `IF` wouldn't help here even if you could use it. Does the table have a primary key or a unique column? You could LEFT JOIN the table to itself on `Product Serial Number` and different ID (or whatever the key column is) and ensure only rows that have A on the left without B on the right are returned

Comment: You need to also show your desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for that, though there are (possibly more complex) other approaches that may only need a single table access.

```
SELECT ... FROM dbo.TableName AS t
WHERE Workflow = 'A'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName AS b
    WHERE b.[Serial Number] = t.[Serial Number]
      AND b.Workflow = 'B'
);
```

- [Other ideas](https://dbfiddle.uk/ydepPWr7), depending on requirements (like whether you want to have serial numbers with only A, or serial numbers with A and anything other than B) and probably some additional information we don't have (like how many possible workflow values are there)

Comment: Perhaps  AND b.Workflow <> 'A' in the where condition should cover most requirements?

Comment: @siggemannen [Perhaps](https://dbfiddle.uk/ydepPWr7). The requirements aren't clear. If there is a row with `7,'A'` and another row with `7,'C'`, is 7 included, or not? I don't know. The question explicitly states _not B_ so it's more likely the current clause matches, and if I change it, well, it can still only work for one requirement or the other. If the OP clarifies, then we'll know.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from myTable t1
where Workflow = 'A' and
      not exists (select * from myTable t2
                  where t1.ProductSerialNumber = t2.ProductSerialNumber
                        and t2.Workflow <> 'A');
```